# Get the current element running in ngFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular

List of images are executing in a loop(ngFor). I am trying to get the current element that is being clicked  by calling the function (click)="addStyle()".The issue I am facing here is ,if i am adding a style [class.active] depending upon the clicked method,it gets reflected in all the image tags.But I am trying to add style to only the particular image being clicked.

**component.html**

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let i of img;let i = index">
    <img class="product-i-2" [src]="i" [class.active]="isActive" (click)="addStyle()">
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
 isActive:false;
 addStyle()
 {
  this.isActive=true;
 }
```

**component.css**

```
.active
{
 border:1px solid red;
 }
```

**In short,I am trying to add style to only particular image tag and not all the images in the loop**

Comment: `(click)="addStyle(i)"` add i to addStyle, and `class.active` should be `img.active`. Rename `let i = index` to `let _i = index` to avoid conflicts with the already declared variable `i`. Alter `addStyle` to set `i.isActive` to `!i.isActive`.

Comment: thanks for the help..but i am still trying to add style to only the particular element that is being clicked

Comment: This will do that. You just need to disable the style on the other elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let i of img;let i = index">
    <img class="product-i-2" [src]="i" [class.active]="i === activeIdx" 
(click)="addStyle(i)">
</div>

activeIdx: number;
addStyle(i)
{
  this.activeIdx = i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let i of img;let j = index">
    <img class="product-i-2" [src]="i" [class.active]="isActive[i] == true ? 'active' : '' " (click)="addStyle(j)">
</div>
```

**TS**

```
isActive: any[] = false;
ngOnInit() {
// here we set defalut value to false
   for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    this.isActive.push(false);
   }
}
 addStyle(j)
 {
  this.isActive[j]= !this.isActive[j];
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass event parameter on click and in that you will get element and than you can add class into it.

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let i of img;let i = index">
    <img class="product-i-2" [src]="i" (click)="addStyle(e)">
</div>

// In TS file

addStyle(event)
{
  event.target.classList.add(className);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is you convert the array of images to array of object of images and mark as active.

```
 ngOnInit(){
  this.img.forEach((img)=>{
  this.alter.push({src:img, isActive:false})
 })
}

 addAlterStyle(index){
   this.alter.forEach((img) => img.isActive = false);
   this.alter[index].isActive = true;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let image of alter;let i = index">
    <img class="product-i-2" [ngClass]="{'isActive':image.isActive}" [src]="image.src" (click)="addAlterStyle(i)">
</div>
```

If you dont want to change the img array structure

**TS**

```
addStyle(event){
    let imageTags = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
    imageTags.forEach((element)=>{
      element.classList.remove('isActive')
    })
    event.target.classList.add('isActive')
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let image of img;let i = index">
    <img class="product-i-2 image" [src]="image" (click)="addStyle($event)">
</div>
```

[Here is the stackblitz working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esbeuj)

Answer (score 1):

don't save isActive property save active Image and then you can check a condition by reference

```
activeImg:any;

addStyle($event){
this.activeImg=$event;
}

<div class="item" *ngFor="let i of img;let i = index">
    <img class="product-i-2" [src]="i" [class.active]="activeImg==i" (click)="addStyle()">
```